# NSInputStream open BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ftp, nsinputstream

The below is my code to upload log files to FTP, and the problem is sometimes it crashes when execute [mInputStream open]. XCode show me BAD_ACCESS. I guess it may result from uploading a big-size file. However, BADACCESS sometimes happens, even file size is small. So I guess size is not the main reason. Anyone can help? Thanks a million.

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

BOOL success;

NSURL *url;
CFWriteStreamRef ftpStream;

mFinish = NO;

mUploadPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[UtilityHelper logFolderPath],   [mPathList objectAtIndex:0]]; 

//NSLog(@"mUpLoadPath:%d",[mUploadPath retainCount]);
[mPathList removeObjectAtIndex:0];

// check url
url = [UtilityHelper smartURLForString:FTP_URL];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", url.absoluteString, [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]]];
success = (url != nil);

if (success) {        
    url = [NSMakeCollectable(CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (CFURLRef) url, (CFStringRef) [mUploadPath lastPathComponent], false) ) autorelease];
    success = (url != nil);
}else
    return;

mInputStream = [[NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:mUploadPath] retain];
[mInputStream open];

// Create CFFTPStream for the URL
ftpStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);

assert(ftpStream != NULL);

mNetworkStream = [(NSOutputStream*)ftpStream retain];

NSLog(@"<<<<<<**>retain count:%d", [mNetworkStream retainCount]);

success = [mNetworkStream setProperty:FTP_USERNAME forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
assert(success);

success = [mNetworkStream setProperty:FTP_PWD forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
assert(success);

//[mNetworkStream self
mNetworkStream.delegate = self;

[mNetworkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[mNetworkStream open];

CFRelease(ftpStream); 

[pool release];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `retainCount` is nonsense.  Don't call it.  Don't try to understand the value returned.

Secondly, your app is crashing.  That means there is a crash log or backtrace.  Post it.

Finally, your question is tagged iOS, but you are calling `NSMakeCollectible()`;  that doesn't make sense.   Also, there appear to be a number of memory management issues here.  Did you try Build and Analyze?